# What's the performance penalty of long lived DB transactions interleaved with one another?

Tags: performance, jpa, transactions

Could anyone provide an explanation or point me to a good source where it is explained the impact of long lived database transactions when there are other transactions involved?

I'm having difficulties trying to understand what is the real impact in the performance of an application of having transactions where most of the queries are reads and maybe a couple or three are writes, given the different isolation levels.

Mostly I would like to understand it in the situation where:

- Neither the rows read nor the rows updated are involved in any other transaction.
- The rows read are involved in another transaction but not the rows being updated and this other transaction is read only.
- The rows read are involved in another transaction but not the rows being updated and this other transaction is modifying some data being read. I understand here it also affects whether the data is read before or after is being modified.
- Both the rows read and the rows updated are involved in another transaction also modifying the data.

These questions come in the context of an application using micro services where all application layer services are annotated with `@Transactional` using `JPA` and `PostgreSQL` and, to transform the data, they need to do some network calls to other micro services within the transaction to fetch some other values.

Comment: That depends very much on if your dbms is MVCC-capable. In that case, the reading of rows has no impact on other transactions except the necessary space, the dbms must provide to keep preimages as long as a reading-transaction is running.

Comment: The DB is PosgreSQL version 9.6. So in that case, the only problem apart from disk space would be the time the connections from the pool are being used, right? What if among some select statements there is a row that is being updated by several open transactions? My understanding is that it depends on the isolation level used so that the only way to guarantee that each write will use the most up to date data from the database is by using the Serializable isolation level. Any other one could result in different results depending on the order of execution of the different transactions involved.

Comment: So given that's the case, the longer the transaction is open the more likely is for a transaction to use stale data. So using MVCC instead of a pessimistic locking strategy, while more performant, is more error prone and to reduce inconsistencies the sooner a transaction is committed the better. Is that correct?

Comment: First Concurrent writes of the same row are synchronized, that does not depend on the isolationlevel. Second: yes, but imO not more error-prone since you always base your changes on a consistent view of the data. What is important, is rhat you correctly handle concurrent changes, either by detection during the change or by preventing using locks.